# Cannot Install sklearn with pip on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, python, pip

I got the following error message when trying to install scikit-learn on a Mac: http://pastebin.com/sfsbqcm6

I tried to install scikit-learn using this command:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

I found on other questions about the `-arch ppc` flag, but I'm not sure how to edit the argument with `pip install scikit-learn` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I realized that I'm using a 32 bit version of Python which wasn't compatible with scipy and gave errors. I followed instructions on how to uninstall python and install 64 bit, and now  I could successfully install scipy, numpy, etc. So check your python version!